# Finding Average and Standard Deviation on displayed, filtered data in Excel Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, standards, average

So I am running into a small problem with my current code. My objective is to filter data in an excel sheet and take the average and standard deviation of that filtered data. Without filtering the data I can display the average and standard deviation. I get values for both the average and standard deviation. However, after I filter the data, I run the macro again, but it is displaying the same average and standard deviation as it did before when the data was not filtered. I was wondering what is wrong with my code or how can I tweak it so it takes the average and standard deviation only on the displayed data.

Here is my code:

'Code for average

```
 Sub Avg()
 Range("F1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Columns("D"))
 End Sub
```

'Code for Std. Dev_S

```
Sub Dev()
Range("G1").Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Columns("D"))) / 1.128
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the subtotal function. The 101 and 107 codes should ignore hidden values. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx

```
Sub Avg()
Range("F1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUBTOTAL(101,Columns("D"))
End Sub

Sub Dev()
Range("G1").Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SUBTOTAL(107,Columns("D"))) / 1.128
End Sub
```

I can't test it right now, let me know if that works!

Comment: Works perfectly Josh! Thanks for the help! I am still new to VBA so I am still learning the context and everything. Appreciate it!

Comment: Wait @Josh DM , i tried manually calculating the given data and the value i got manually was different from the value calculated from the code.

Comment: This only happens when I do not filter the categories consecutively.  The categories apparently have to be consecutive in order for this to work.

Comment: For both the average and standard deviation? Keep in mind you are dividing the standard deviation by 1.128 (I'm sure you have a reason) and the 107 function code is the sample standard deviation. Are you dividing by 1.128 when you calculate manually? And are you using the sample std formula or population std formula? You can use the 108 formula for population std.

Comment: @adit123 I'm not too sure what you mean by filtering consecutively

Comment: correct. I made sure when I calculated manually that I was dividing by 1.128, also I am using the sample std formula. That is the one I have to use. Also by filtering consecutively, I mean that I have to filter by date. So if I filer by June, July, August. The information is correct. However, if I filter, for example: April, June, July, August. The values are different.

Comment: @adit123 I did some testing, and I could not replicate such behaviour :( Everything seemed to work fine.